# How to assign specific user role an user in key-cloak via rest api?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When a new user is created via rest API endpoint, how to add user role to the newly created user?

Answer (score 2):

1. At the initial user creation endpoint role is not included. First, we need to create the user via rest API endpoint. post request domain/auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users
2. Then we want to add a user role to the created user. For that, we should have the username of the created user. If you've enabled email as username in the key-cloak. You can fetch user data from the key-cloak via that email.
3. To fetch user data via username below endpoint is used. get request domain/auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users?username="emailToTest@test.com".
4. To assign role to the user we can use below post endpoint domain/auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users/{user_id}/role-mappings/realm

pass an array with below structure in the request body.

[
{
"id": "role id", *you can get role id once you click on a specific role and on the URL there is the id*
"name" :"role name"
},
{
"id":"role id", "name":"role name"
}
]

Comment: It works for me, Thanks!
"domain/auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users/{user_id}/role-mappings/realm"